# Как загрузить List из XML?

Tags: c#, xml

```
class TMenu
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<TMenu> GetMenu()
        {
            return new List<TMenu>
            {
                new TMenu {id = 1, ParentID = 0 , Title="Title1" , url = "www.example.com" },
                new TMenu {id = 2, ParentID =1 , Title="Title2" , url = "www.example.com" },
                new TMenu {id = 3, ParentID =1 , Title="Title3" , url = "www.example.com" },
                new TMenu {id = 4, ParentID =3 , Title="Title4" , url = "www.example.com" },
                new TMenu {id = 5, ParentID =3 , Title="Title5" , url = "www.example.com" },
                new TMenu {id = 6, ParentID =1 , Title="Title6" , url = "www.example.com" },
                new TMenu {id = 7, ParentID =6 , Title="Title7" , url = "www.example.com" },
                new TMenu {id = 8, ParentID =1 , Title="Title8" , url = "www.example.com" }
            };
        }
    }
```

Как видно `List<TMenu>` формируется вручную. А как сделать загрузку данных из xml вместо ручного заполнения в коде?

**UPD:** Показываю свой xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap id="0" parentid="-1" title="Title" url="http://example.com">

    <siteMapNode id="1" parentid="0" title="Title" url="http://example.com">
        <siteMapNode id="2" parentid="1" title="Title"url="http://example.com"></siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode id="3" parentid="1" title="Title" url="http://example.com"></siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode id="4" parentid="0" Title="Title" url="http://example.com">
    </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode id="5" parentid="0" title="Title" url="http://example.com">
    </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode id="6" parentid="0" title="Title"  url="http://example.com">
        <siteMapNode id="7" parentid="6" title="Title" url="http://example.com">
    </siteMapNode>

    </siteMapNode>

</siteMap>
```

Comment: Легко. Покажите свой XML.

Comment: Как я понимаю, это через LINQ решается, но я имею слишком мало опыта с LINQ, чтобы сделать что-то большее чем select().

Comment: Угу, сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть много путей. Например, можно так:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("menu.xml");
var result = doc.Descendants("siteMapNode")
                .Select(e => new TMenu()
                             {
                                 id = (int)e.Attribute("id"),
                                 ParentID = (int)e.Attribute("parentid"),
                                 Title = (string)e.Attribute("title"),
                                 url = (string)e.Attribute("url")
                             })
                .ToList();
```

---

Преимущество этого подхода перед «полновесной» XML-сериализацией в том, что вам не нужна тяжеловесная расстановка атрибутов `[XmlAttribute]`, `[XmlElement]` и т. п.

**UPD, для тех кто придет сюда из гугла:** Не забудьте `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: а через XmlSerializer, или как-то так не получилось бы?

Comment: @Grundy: Получилось бы, но слишком уж enterprisey..

Comment: _тяжеловесная расстановка атрибутов_ = это типа тяжело руками ставить? :-) или на производительность влияет?

Comment: @Grundy: Это слишком много кода для слишком маленького результата — потом его ж ещё и читать надо. Хуже того, это заставляет класс `TMenu` _знать_, что его будут сериализировать, что в принципе может быть и не важно для него.

Comment: Получил `the non generic type system collections ienumerable cannot be used with type arguments`. Дописал `using System.Collections.Generic;`. Ошибка пропала, но получил Сервер Эррор ин Эплекейшен. Сейчас буду деббажить - странно, что такое получилось.

Comment: Ага, я не правильно поставил путь к файлу

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron: Поставьте breakpoint на `result =` и посмотрите, отрабатывает ли код.

Comment: Поправил путь к файлу, все отлично.

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron: Вот и хорошо!

Answer (score 1):

```
private TMenu LoadSettingsFromFile(string fileName)
{
    // Constructs an instance of the XmlSerializer with the type
    // of object that is being deserialized.
    XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TMenu));
    // To read the file, creates a FileStream.
    FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
    // Calls the Deserialize method and casts to the object type.
    TMenu tmenu = (TMenu)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
    myFileStream.Close();
    return tmenu;
}
```

В классе нужно указать к каким полям маппится сериализатору с помощью атрибутов

```
[XmlIgnore] - что пропускать
[XmlElement("Целевой элемент")]
[XmlAttribute("целевой атрибут")]
```

Comment: что за ManagerSettings, [XmlElement("WebService")]? как это относится к вопросу?

Comment: Это класс (вместо WebService используйте ваш класс), сериализатор автоматически маппит публичные поля класса. [XmlElement("WebService")] - это для указания сериализутору что мапить

Comment: стоит отредактировать код, чтобы он соответствовал примеру xml в вопросе, а так же написать пояснения что именно в нем происходит. На данный момент этот код _никак_ нельзя применить к тому что указано в вопросе. В каком классе лежат эти методы? нужны ли еще какие-либо настройки для класса `ManagerSettings`?

Comment: Спасибо за решение, но я пока к таким сложным штукам как серелизация не готов.

Comment: На самом деле все не так сложно. Это гораздо проще чем разбирать xml-документ, при этом если поменяется элемент, то достаточно добавить/удалить соответствующее поле в классе

Comment: Звучит действительно не сложно и приятно. В следующий раз попробую так и сделать. Спасибо за подробный, интересный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из названий тегов можно сделать вывод, что вы работаете с sitemap.xml, который используется в ASP.NET-приложениях.

Для работы с sitemap предназначен класс **XmlSiteMapProvider**.

Надо заменить, что sitemap может состоять из частей, находящихся в разных файлах. Например, в sitemap.xml может находиться тег с ссылкой на другой файл

```
<siteMapNode siteMapFile="child.sitemap" />
```

Класс XmlSiteMapProvider позволяет прозрачно работать с sitemap, состоящим из разных частей.